# Javascript How do i select the first option element from html?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm a beginner at javascript. How do i select in javascript the first option in html "`<option value="">Choose an image...</option>`"? *without changing the html?

My guess is this: `memeForm.getElementById('meme-image').getElementByName('option')`
??

I want to select this so that if the user picks this one (which is the default) they get an error message. Thanks in advance.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(e){
    const memeForm = document.querySelector('.meme-form');

    memeForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if()

        });
})
```

```html
<form class="meme-form">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="meme-image">Meme Image</label>
    <select name="memeImage" id="meme-image">
      <option value="">Choose an image...</option>
      <option value="cat-meme">Cat Meme</option>
      <option value="dog-meme">Dog Meme</option>
      <option value="man-meme">Man Man</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  const memeForm = document.querySelectorAll('select option')[0];
  console.log(memeForm.value)
})
```

```html
<form class="meme-form">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="meme-image">Meme Image</label>
    <select name="memeImage" id="meme-image">
      <option value="...">Choose an image...</option>
      <option value="fry-meme">Fry Meme</option>
      <option value="one-does-not-simply-meme">One Does Not Simply Meme</option>
      <option value="most-interesting-man-meme">Most Interesting Man</option>
    </select>
```

or:

```
  const memeForm = document.querySelector('select option:first-of-type');
```

or numerous other ways from reported duplicate topic...

Also you should just use HTML `selected disabled` for this:

```html
<form class="meme-form">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="meme-image">Meme Image</label>
    <select name="memeImage" id="meme-image">
      <option value="..." selected disabled>Choose an image...</option>
      <option value="fry-meme">Fry Meme</option>
      <option value="one-does-not-simply-meme">One Does Not Simply Meme</option>
      <option value="most-interesting-man-meme">Most Interesting Man</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a "disabled" prop to the option, so the user won't be able to choose it once the select combo is open.

```
<option disabled value="">Choose an image...</option>
```